# how to pass data from controller to jquery (Ajax) in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

controller code

```
$rates['poor'] = 10; 
$rates['fair'] = 20;

$this->load->view('search_result2', $rates);

//I have tried this in many ways but at least It executes the "success" in ajax file only with above way.  other ways I have tried ex :-
//$this->output->set_output(json_encode($rates));
//echo json_encode($rates);
```

i need to pass this rates array to ajax

js code

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'some url',
    data:{'adID':adID},
    //dataType:'JSON', // when I uncommented this it displays nothing. when commented it displays "undefined" on the label below i have created
    success:function(rates){ 

        $('#rate_val').html('<label>'+rates.poor+'</label>');

        //I have tried this in many ways  ex :-
        // $('#rate_val').html('<label>'+rates['poor']+'</label>');
        // $('#rate_val').html('<label>'+rates[0]+'</label>');

    }
});
```

this displays "undefined" on label. I can't get the data I have passed from controller. please help ?

Comment: `echo json_encode($rates);` should be fine. Try to access the URL from browser and see what the result is.

Comment: use this `echo json_encode($rates);` and put `die;` after `echo` statement

Comment: @KarelG - i accessed by using url it displays  {"poor":10} but still i get "undefined" on the label

Comment: i think now the error is with this 

$('#rate_val').html('<label>'+rates.poor+'</label>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uncomment `dataType:'JSON'`
2. Set output as json with `echo` or `set_output` from controller
3. Get item with `rates.poor` or `rates['poor']` from ajax

**Controller**

```
public function post_url()
{
    $rates = array();
    $rates['poor'] = 10; 
    $rates['fair'] = 20;

    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($rates));
}
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'POST_URL',
    data:{'adID':adID},
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(rates){ 
        $('#rate_val').html('<label>'+rates.poor+'</label>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['a']='100';
$data['b']='200';
echo json_encode(array('success'=>$data));
```

jquery

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'POST_URL',
    data:{'adID':adID},
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(rates){
       var data     = jQuery.parseJSON('['+response+']');

        $('#rate_val').html('<label>'+data.succcess.a+'</label><label>'+data.succcess.b+'</label>');
    }
});
</script>
```

i believe it may execute as you want to .