# How to pass variable from Controller to View with Ajax in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with passing data from Controller to View.

I am using Ajax to do this, you can see my Ajax code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.thang').click(function(){
        var id_thang = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'/Home/getImage',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_thang: id_thang},
        }).done(function(result) {
            console.log(result.get_list_image_thang);
        })          
    });
});
```

I will get `id_thang` when clicking in HTML tags `li > thang`.

At `Controller / Home.php`, I will get an array data on this `id_thang`.

```
function getImage(){
    $id_thang = $this->input->post('id_thang');
    $input = array();
    $input['order'] = array('id','ASC');
    $get_image_thang  = $this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);
    ob_start();
}
```

All data is stored in array `$get_image_thang`.

Finally, I don't know how to pass this array to View show all data I selected.

In View/index.php I am trying a `foreach` loop through all data in this array and show in `<html>` tag. Like this:

```
<?php foreach($get_image_thang AS $item) ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <?php echo $item->id; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Note: at `View / index.php` is demo code.

Problem is I don't know how to send `$get_image_thang` to this View.

Update 1:

I tried to put: `console.log(result);` to `.done(function(result)` event and receive result like this:

[image]

Problem is: I use `row +=  result[i].id;` or any property like `id`, `name`, `image_list` is not undefined.

**Update 2:**

Only two function to get info base on `id`. I write all code in `core/MY_MODEL.php`:

```
function get_info($id, $field = '')
{
    if (!$id)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $where = array();
    $where[$this->key] = $id;

    return $this->get_info_rule($where, $field);
}

function get_info_rule($where = array(), $field= '')
{
    if($field)
    {
        $this->db->select($field);
    }
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    if ($query->num_rows())
    {
        return $query->row();
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

At controller, I call `get_info`. Note:

`Mmenushoatnao` is a Model maps in database.

**Update 3:**

I only know write code in `Controller` to get data after `click` event.

But like your question mention. Must write all code in Ajax code.

Like this:

```
function getImage(){
    $id_thang = $this->input->post('id_thang');
    $input = array();
    $input['order'] = array('id','ASC');
    $get_image_thang  = $this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <?php foreach($get_image_thang as $item): ?>
    <?php $image_list = json_decode($item->image_list); ?>
    <?php foreach($image_list as $image): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <img src="<?php echo upload_url() ?>/img/hoatnao/hinhanh/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php
    $return  = ob_get_clean();
    $data['result']=$return;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Of course, this code is not working.

So, we need convert to Ajax code.

Comment: could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776918/how-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-jquery-ajax-in-codeigniter

Comment: @exiang no duplicate. your reference link is pass data from a controller to Ajax. In this question, I tried to get data from controller and send back to View.

Comment: `$this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);` show this `get_info()` method code

Comment: I updated `get_info()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
function getImage(){
    $id_thang = $this->input->post('id_thang');
    $input = array();
    $input['order'] = array('id','ASC');
    $get_image_thang  = $this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);
    echo json_encode($get_image_thang);
}
```

Now in ajax (assuming you are returning object from `get_info()` method)

```
//....
.done(function(result) {
   var row = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
         row +=  result[i].id;
    }
   $('#res').html(row);
 })
```

before it, provide any ID in your view page where you want to show this result

```
<div id="res" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

</div>
```

Comment: I want to show all values of JSON.

Seem it only print like: `[object Object] 1` or `object Object] 2`.

Comment: Use `result.id` (in ajax done) as you are using `row()` in model which returns only a single row from dataset (first row). If you need all results then use `result()` (in model) instead `row()`

Comment: sorry couldn't realize what you want to say

Comment: That mean: I don't know how to add `<html>` tag like: `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">` or convert a JSON to an array with `php` code: `<?php $image_list = json_decode($item->image_list); ?>`. I see your answer can be access to all property of JSON through by Ajax code. And I don't know how to write this code in Ajax code. Are you know my problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125554/discussion-between-vn-lc-and-rejoanul-alam).

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm noticing you haven't set your data to JSON output i would recommend you take a look at the output class in the [codeigniter guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html), Also how you need to decode The JSON in your controller I will leave a reference for you [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) reading the link will give you a better understanding of how to decode the JSON fore example it takes a second parameter that turn your JSON into an array.

```
function getImage(){
    $id_thang = $this->input->post('id_thang');
    $id_thang = json_decode($id_thang); // decode JSON to work with it.
    $input = array();// im guessing this is the array you want to send back as JSON
    $input['order'] = array('id','ASC');
    $get_image_thang  = $this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);
    ob_start();// I have no clue you want to achieve with this function? more info on this would be good.

    $this->output
      ->set_content_type('application/json')
      ->set_output(json_encode(array(YOUR ARRAY HERE)));

}
```

This should be the last thing in your controller for it's the output.I would also like to know if you can share what the console says.

Another thing I noticed is that you don't stringify your data when sending it through $.ajax example ;

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li.thang').click(function(){
            var id_thang = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl+'/Home/getImage',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                // this is where you should stringify your JSON
                data: {id_thang: JSON.stringify(id_thang)},
            }).done(function(result) {
                console.log(result.get_list_image_thang);
            })          
        });
    });
```

I would like to have more info on what the actuall controller is doing and how your returning your query from the model your using to get a better insight and help your furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get json data from remote, you can output your result by

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

It will integrate to the result variable from ajax method, and then handle it as array.